# How to search without zoom and put marker on all locations in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I would like for Google Maps to produce me a map of all items searched for.

1. Take current zoom level
2. Put in search parameters
3. Map puts marker on every result (without zooming in)

For example: Zoom out to US continental level. Search for "Walmart". Then map puts a marker/star at every Walmart in the continental US.

Zoom in to Utah. Type McDonalds. Now you have a map of every McDonalds in Utah.

Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User. Please add details about your context. Tell us how you started Google Maps, and tell us about how it looks. This is relevant because the experience of each user might vary depending on several factors like the web browser used, the user location, if they are using a shared computer, if the user has signed in using a Google consumer / Gmail account or a school / work account, among many other things.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what Google Maps does:

1. The user zooms in the area that you want to obtain search results
2. Then you type your search criteria
3. Click search

I zoomed to Spain, and look for all McDonald's.

[image]

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User. It looks like you used the Google Maps app for mobile instead of the app for the web. This question is about using apps for the Web, which might work differently. Please confirm that the app for the web works the same way.